# How do websites verify that a user is logged in securely?

Tags: security, authentication, cookies

I can't seem to find any answers to this. How do websites (I'm combining mine with external PHP but that doesn't matter) securely verify that a user is logged in? I'm assuming they set a login token in a database but what do they compare the database's token to? Do they add the token as a cookie or is there a more secure way of storing it? How do these things work? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in serval ways.
Most used is a cookie-session with a session/hash-value.
There could be added serval features to make it bit more safe as sample with comparing the remote adress, if they match.

Comment: So when the users logs in, you set a session cookie with a random token in it and add the token to a database. When they want to access a restricted page, the webpage checks the cookie against an entry in a database. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, the (almost)session-id or a sessionhash is used right in this way for checking the login session.
In older scripts you sometimes see a get variable in the adress like
&sid=xyzxxxxxx...
This method is used, when cookies are not available/disabled.

Comment: Would it be fine to have a remember me button that sets an actual cookie or is there a more secure way of doing that

Comment: The cookie can be ordered to set in your backend without a remember-me btn. A remember-me btn you could use to let choose, if the session is a temporary session (if browser will be closed the session is destroyed/no longer valid) or a static session (when the browser is re-opened, the loginsession is valid and the user dont need to re-login.) Most secure is the temporary session like bank-webpages and additional a remote-ip verification to be safe against session- / cookie-thifs. (if the current remote-ip dont match the ip, where the session/cookie was created -> let destroy the session.